# 'ISO-8859-1' characters no more readable in 'UTF-8'

Tags: php, character-encoding, mb-convert-encoding

I have an issue when i try to convert encoding in PHP with `mb_convert_encoding` function.

The main idea is to change the format of a 'CSV' file which has an 'ISO-8859-1' encoding. I want the output formatted 'CSV' be in 'UTF-8' encoding and be readable just like the input.

`mb_convert_encoding` gets the job done, however, when i try to open the formatted CSV with Notepad++ i get bizarre characters instead of the Greek ones which the 'ISO-8859-1' original CSV had.

Why is that?

Comment: "Gets the job done" sounds like there's nothing wrong with the resulting file, but Notepad++ doesn't display it correctly?

Comment: What encoding does Notepad++ think it is?  (See bottom right of the screen.)

Comment: Notepad++ think it is 'ANSI as UTF-8'.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is probably opening the file as ASCII. Click Encoding -> UTF-8